# Is integrability a sufficient condition for boundness?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, upper-lower-bounds

*Prove that $f(x,y)$ which satisfies:
$$|f(x,y)-f(x,z)|\leq h(x)|y-z|$$
$$h(x): (0,a]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, \text{integrable function}$$*
is Lipschitz with respect to $y$.

**Attempt:**

For $f$ to satisfy the Lipschitz condition, it must be shown that
$$h(x) \leq k$$
for some positive constant $k$.

I know that functions which are continuous on a closed bounded interval are bounded, but I'm far from proving the continuity of $h$, plus its domain is not a closed interval.

Comment: What is the question behind this special question? There are proofs of Picard-Lindelöf that can take directly the function $h$ and provide convergence of the Picard iteration, without establishing a local Lipschitz condition in your sense. A sketch of that I wrote yesterday in the last part of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2987844/115115

Comment: @LutzL Yes. I am trying to show that $$y'=f(x,y), \quad y(0)=0$$ $$0\leq x \leq a, \quad |y|\leq b$$ has a unique solution.

Comment: You don't want to show that the function is Lipschitz... Simply apply Gronwall's lemma: it gives you immediately the uniqueness (although your question asks about the Lipschitz property, which is obvious for Riemann integrable, by definition, and clearly false for Lebesgue integrable, you need to choose one).

Comment: @JohnB How does the Gronwall Lemma apply here?

Comment: That's not your question, you need to ask another question for that. But really you need to make an effort instead of asking so many related questions.

Comment: I'm trying to make an effort through asking those questions for hints and working them out simultaneously. I'm an undergrad and this kind of qualitative analysis of ode's is new to me.