# Using Picard-Lindelof to find a solution to $y'(t,y(t))=t+\sin(y(t))$ where $y(2)=1.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

Consider the initial value problem $y'(t,y(t))=t+sin(y(t))$ with initial condition $y(2)=1$. Find the largest interval $\mathcal{I}\subset \mathbb{R}$ containing $t_0=2$ such that the problem has a unique solutions $y$ in $\mathcal{I}$.

---

I've been trying to apply Picard-Lindelof theorem to this problem and I got that $M=\underset{R}{\sup}y'(t,y(t))=a+2+\sin(b+1)$. Where $R=\{(t,y):|t-2|\leq a, |y-1|\leq b \}$.

I know that the interval is $\mathcal{I}=[2-\varepsilon, 2 + \varepsilon]$ where $\varepsilon = \min(a, b/M)$. I also know that in order for $\mathcal{I}$ to be the largest possible, $a$ must equal $b/M$.

As $M$ depends on $a$, you cannot make $a$ to big without $b/M$ getting too small. This looks like a maximization problem here. I ended up getting a very nasty value for $\varepsilon$. So I believe I am wrong.

Anyone have any hints?

Comment: You got $y$, where it exists, satisfying $|y'|\le 3+|t-2|$ so that $|y(t)-y(2)|\le3|t-2|+\frac12|t-2|^2$. Which means that there are no singularities at finite times.

Comment: @LutzL Are you saying that the biggest interval would be the whole real line?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You also got a global Lipschitz constant $1$, which is in itself an argument for global existence.

Comment: @LutzL So I attempted my own proof of it over here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004533/find-the-largest-interval-where-the-initial-value-problem-yt-tsinyt-wi Do you mind having a look and telling me if it is correct?

Comment: Following the lines of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2987844/115115 you get a modified norm $$\|y\|_w=\sup_{t\in\Bbb R} e^{-2|t-2|}\|y(t)\|,$$ and relative to this norm the Picard iteration is a contraction on $C(\Bbb R)$, thus has a unique fixed point which is also a solution of the ODE by the Banach fixed-point theorem.