# global and unique solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y' = f(x) p(\cos y) + g(x) q( \sin y) $ and $y(0) =1$, with $f,g$ continuous and $p,q$ polynomials. Then there exists unique solution on all $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Its easily solved if i assumed that $f,g$ are bounded, but the question asks about $f,g$ that are not necessarily bounded.

Can any one give a hint or a solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $g$ are bounded on every interval $[-R,R]$ for any $R=N\in\Bbb N$. Thus you get unique solutions over these intervals, and by the uniqueness the solution for $R=N+1$ extends the solution for $R=N$. In the limit this gives a unique solution over all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you tell please, what theorem are you referring to?

Comment: What do you mean, that a global Lipschitz constant on $(t,y)\in [a,b]\times \Bbb R^n$ ensures the existence of a solution over $[a,b]$? This is a variant of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: If you remember the reference with a proof for this variant and can tell me, I would be very grateful!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2987844/115115 and linked posts. I know this variant from my lectures, I do not know which books one could cite. There is also a variant of this global proof that uses the Lipschitz constants of the iterates of the Picard iteration, which fall faster than simply the power of the Lipschitz constant of one iteration.